# Build the feature matrix and label vector:

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a dataset “Digit” . The dataset includes 1797 small images (8x8 pixels), each one includes a hand-written digit (0-9). Each image is considered as a data sample with pixels as features. Thus, to build the feature table you have to convert each 8x8 image into a row of the feature matrix with 64 feature columns for 64 pixels. How to build a feature matrix and label vector for it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the scikit-learn tutorial on supervised learning, where they are using the Digit dataset

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#loading-an-example-dataset

with more detail [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-digits-classification-py). If you load the dataset as in the example, you can simple reshape the images:

```
from sklearn import datasets
digits = datasets.load_digits()
# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(digits.images)
data = digits.images.reshape((n_samples, -1))
```

This makes `data` a 2D matrix, with `n_samples` rows and as many columns as needed to fit the flattened image.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `numpy` and `cv2` you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

fname = "image1.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(fname)                    #  (8, 8, 1)

feature = image.reshape(64)                #  (64,)
```

to read a bunch of images and load into a 'feature matrix' (a `numpy` array) you can do the following:

```
N = 10 # number of images
data = np.zeros((N, 64))

for index in range(N):

    # get the current image and convert to feature, as above

    data[index] = np.copy(feature)
```

Each row of your data matrix is now one example (a 64 dim list of features).

Does this help?

The label vector can just be a 1D numpy array, i.e. `labels = np.zeros(N)`

EDIT:

There are a number of ways to read images:

(1) `img = cv2.imread(filename)`

(2) using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread(filename)
```

(3) using PIL (or PILLOW):

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open(filename)
```

It pays to check the shape of the image after it has been read, so that you know it is in the correct channel, width, height order that is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Sorry but i do not have any idea about cv2 module , is there any way we can do without it ?

Comment: Absolutely, I've update the answer to the three most popular methods. It's most likely you'll have matplotlib installed as part of any python distribution you're using, so I'd recommend that one. cv2 is the python opencv module - it's quite useful for performing general image manipulations.

Comment: I have 1797 images in  a folder, how to load all images in a numpy array ??

Comment: You should use (and probably accept) the answer from @KPLauritzen below, as it is exactly what you need for this question. Otherwise, to load an image you can find more details at http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/

Comment: So i got it and converted it into feature matrix and label vector and applied random forest  and got an accuracy of around 92 % . Is there any way i could list all the misclassified images?

Comment: Yep but it's outside of the scope of this question and these comments now, as that is general python knowledge. I would recommend taking a python course.